# How can I make popover menu on v-menu vuetify 2 auto display on top or bottom

Tags: vuetify.js

When space of bottom is not enough space then popover will be display at top, and otherwise it will be display at bottom.

I have found vuetify 2 document but it not support. In vuetify 3 support.
https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#offset-y

In vuetify 3, menu auto display at top when bottom space is not enough.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#location